# Markov DTMC and CTMC: How to build a $Q$ generating matrix using given $2$ state $q$ probabilities? Find Steady State Probabilities

Tags: probability, markov-chains, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, exponential-distribution

I know that $$q_{(i,j)(i+1,j)}=\lambda_1$$
$$q_{(i,j)(i-1,j+1)}=\lambda_2$$
$$q_{(i,j)(i+1,j-1)}=0.5\lambda_3$$
$$q_{(i,j)(i,j-1)}=0.5\lambda_3$$
where $\lambda_1 , \lambda_2 , \lambda_3 $ are rates of exponential distribution.

I'm trying to write down the $Q$ matrix to solve for stationary probabilities using:
$(\pi_0,\pi_1 ... \pi_n)Q=0$

I don't know how to write this $Q$ matrix down. I'm not sure how to define these $\pi_i$ , do I need to have it in $2$ variables like $\pi_{i,j}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CTMC on a finite state space can be presented in two equivalent ways:

1. As a generator matrix $Q$
2. As a transition probability matrix $P$ and average holding times $\tau_i$ for each $i \in S$.

This $P$ is the transition probability matrix of a certain DTMC, which is called the jump chain of the original CTMC.

To go from 1 to 2, you do one of two things for each $i$.

1. If $Q_{ii}=0$ then $P_{ii}=1,P_{ij}=0$ for $j \neq i$ and $\tau_i=+\infty$.
2. If $Q_{ii} \neq 0$ then $P_{ii}=0,P_{ij}=-\frac{Q_{ij}}{Q_{ii}}$ and $\tau_i=-\frac{1}{Q_{ii}}$.

To go from 2 to 1, take $Q_{ii}=-\frac{1}{\tau_i}$ and $Q_{ij}=-P_{ij} Q_{ii}$.

The stationary distribution $\pi$ is not yours to define, it is the solution of a system of equations.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how it works for a "single" state, but in my case I have pairs of $(i,j)$ changing to $(i+1,j)$ for example. I don't know what my matrix $Q$ would represent? Will it look like $(0,0), (0,1) , (1,0) (1,1) , (1,2) , (2,1),  (2,2) , (2,3),(3,2) (3,3) ... (n,n) $ And under this line, I need to fill in the corresponding probabilities, so $q_{(1,1)(2,1)}=\lambda 1$ and it goes into the 4th row, 6th column?

Comment: @GRS Something like this, yes; you need to pick a way of emlnumerating your states with one index rather than two.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, because I couldn't figure out how I'd find the stationary probabilities

Comment: I could probably use the total number $i+j$ in the system and solve for steady state, anyway I'll think some more about it.

Comment: @GRS No, $i+j$ will not work, because $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ have the same sum etc. The most straightforward enumerations are the two possible lexicographic orders.